# How to replace a comma into different string array value using php?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

Getting hard time to fix this one, please help me :(

```
$string = "Question 1 , Question 2, Question 3"; // Value came from Database;
```

My code is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ $alphas = range('A', 'C');
            $output = str_replace(',', ('<br/>'.$alphas[$row]), $string);
            echo $output
}
```

The Result will be like this:

```
Question 1

Question 2

Question 3
```

What I want is , every comma will change into different value

```
A. Question 1

B. Question 2

C. Question 3
```

Please help me guys! thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Question 1 , Question 2, Question 3";

$arr=explode(',',$string);
$alphas = range('A', 'C');

$final=array();


for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {

$final[]=$alphas[$i].'. '.trim($arr[$i]).'<br>';

}

echo(join($final));
```

Comment: Omg It works thank you so much ^_^ what a great help!